# Wix custom BA installer WPF Launch App after install completes

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.9

I've created a custom installer using a WIX and WPF project.
I'm trying to implement launching application after installer finish successfully.
When i use Process.Start(AppPath); it does not strart the file from the specified path but uses path from the temporary files.
In common cases using

```
<Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[InstallFolder]\pCloud Drive\pCloud.exe"/>
```

would result in a button in the Finish page but i'm making my custom UI so this is not working.

Edit
Somehow now it is working. I'm using

```
if (LaunchApp)
{
    ProcessStartInfo exeFile = new ProcessStartInfo(this.AppPath);
    Process.Start(exeFile);
}

///don't call Environment.Exit. The BA is a guest in the process, Bootstrapper.Engine.Quit is how you tell Burn that you're done. Burn will call ExitProcess from there.
WixBootstrapper.BootstrapperDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
```